# How to validate mobile number on angular material reactive form?

Tags: regex, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

**app.component.ts**

```
phoneFormControl = new FormControl('', [
Validators.required,
Validators.pattern("[6-9]\d{9}")
])
```

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Phone Number" [formControl]="phoneFormControl>
    <mat-error *ngIf="phoneFormControl.hasError('required')">
         Phone Number is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Error on form submission**

```
pattern:
   actualValue: "9120227914"
   requiredPattern: "^[6-9]d{9}$"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your pattern is a `string`, it should have the backslash escaped.

So, instead of `Validators.pattern("[6-9]\d{9}")`, you want `Validators.pattern("[6-9]\\d{9}")`.

**Sample**:

```
readonly phoneFormControl = new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required, Validators.pattern(("[6-9]\\d{9}"))
]);
```

[**`Working demo`**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zb45gw)